Can someone help me with the Pinescript below
I'm struggling with the Pinescript as below. Instead of calculating the take profit/stop loss level based on the high/low of entry candle, it calculates the level based on the high/low of the next qualify candle. Can someone help me on this. Thank you.
//@version=5
strategy("EMA5 & EMA100 strategy", overlay=true)

// Calculate EMAs using ta.ema function
ema100 = ta.ema(close, 100)
ema5 = ta.ema(close, 5)

// Determine trend
trend = na(ema100[1]) ? ta.crossover(ema100, ema5) : ema5 > ema100 ? 1 : -1

// Filter signals
buySignal = trend == 1 and ema100 < close and close < ema5 and close < open
sellSignal = trend == -1 and ema100 > close and close > ema5 and close > open

// Enter positions
if buySignal
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, stop=ta.highest(1)) // No stop argument needed for limit orders
    var float entrybuy_low = na
    var float entrybuy_high = na
    if buySignal == true
        entrybuy_low :=low
        entrybuy_high :=high
    TP = entrybuy_high + (entrybuy_high - entrybuy_low)  // Take profit = entry high + distance to entry low (1:1 ratio)
    SL = entrybuy_low // Stop loss = entry low - distance to entry high (1:1 ratio)
    strategy.exit("Buy TP", "Buy", limit=TP, stop=SL)  // Set limit order exits
if sellSignal
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short,stop=ta.lowest(1)) // No stop argument needed for limit orders
    var float entrysell_low = na
    var float entrysell_high = na
    if sellSignal == true
        entrysell_low :=low
        entrysell_high :=high
    TP1 = entrysell_low - (entrysell_high - entrysell_low)  // Take profit = entry low - distance to entry high (1:1 ratio)
    SL1 = entrysell_high  // Stop loss = entry high + distance to entry low (1:1 ratio)
    strategy.exit("Sell TP", "Sell", limit=TP1, stop=SL1)  // Set limit order exits

// Display information
plotshape(buySignal, color=color.green, style=shape.arrowup, text="Buy", location=location.bottom)
plotshape(sellSignal, color=color.red, style=shape.arrowdown, text="Sell", location=location.top)
plot(ta.ema(close, 100), color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(ta.ema(close, 5), color=color.orange, linewidth=2)


Expecting someone can help me to solve this problem

Have you tried utilizing bar indexes for the signal candles?:
TP = entrybuy_high[1] + (entrybuy_high[1] - entrybuy_low[1])
SL = entrybuy_low[1]
TP1 = entrysell_low[1] - (entrysell_high[1] - entrysell_low[1])
SL1 = entrysell_high[1]
Or have you tried bar states (bartate.ishistory) or similar usage for the signal candles?
